# ELK logstash connecting with Azure Service Bus

Tags: azure, logstash-configuration, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-servicebus-topics, elk

I have set up ELK on a local computer and Logstash get data from stdin without any problems.
I wanted to connect input the Logstash with Azure Service Bus, but I can't find any example how to do it.

Is it possible to connect the two services?

Answer (score 1):

At this moment there is this (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/master/azure-module.html)

You can write some code and schedule it to grab data from Azure Monitor too: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-metrics-azure-monitor

Comment: So, in the situation, if I want to use my queue in Azure Service Bus for sending data with custom data which I am creating, that it isn't possible?

Comment: as far as I know, you'll need to combine a few services for it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-end-to-end-tracing and then, send the data to your ELK stack.